# Is there a genAI which can describe an input image in Chinese?

Tags: image, chinese

I'm looking for a genAI where you input an image, and tell it to 看图写话 (look at the image and write), and it describes the image, i.e., image-to-text.  I'd like to use it for language practice.

I found [astica](https://www.astica.org/vision/describe/) and [CLIP Interrogator](https://huggingface.co/spaces/pharmapsychotic/CLIP-Interrogator) which work for English.  And [VisualGLM](https://huggingface.co/spaces/lykeven/visualglm-6b) used to work for Chinese, but now it just says:

> 超时！请稍等几分钟再重试。
> Timeout! Please wait a few minutes and retry.

**Question**: Is there a genAI which can describe an input image in Chinese?

Answer (score 0):

ChatGPT should be able to do it (specifically I'm using paid version), just ask it to answer in Chinese. I use voice input and mixing English with Chinese and it has no issue to understand.

Answer (score 0):

GPT-4 likely can, Gemini and Claude 3 possibly also.

Do you want a open-source solution or a commercial is fine? Because I would start with the three above.

For open-source a multimodal LLM model is more likely to achieve this or you will have to search for a model already trainned on Chinese or train one yourself. Some of those are LLava, ImageBind, NextGPT and etc.

Other possibility is using a model to describe the image in english and a smaller model to translate the description for Chinese.